# My PC was infected by belombrea dot com. Kaspersky didn't detect it. Is a factory reset enough?

Tags: malware, account-security, anomaly-detection

Also I had it for around 3 days. It downloaded a file that's 1kb big on my PC. What should I do? I'm afraid to use my PC again.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106596/discussion-on-question-by-jasonsampeter-my-pc-was-infected-by-belombrea-dot-com).

Comment: Thanks.  How do I start a chat with another user?

Comment: This really isn't a social media site. It's not easy. There are public rooms, not direct messaging.